# Northgard Edditor Clans

Tags: northgard

The game has a rather good editor allowing you to create new maps with all kinds of features. But is there also a way to change the factions involved?

The game starts with X amount(based on map size) of (random) factions and you are able to add new ones...but the new ones are always Wolfs. Is there a way to choose a other clan for the faction? Kinda a must for balance seeing the map i am making is a bit of a gimmick map and only a few clans would actually be able to properly play the game on it.

[image: Northgard Factions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new update allows clans to be changed by selecting the townhall, revealing a drop down menu of all clans.